# fancyhdr - anomalous behaviour on first page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am having trouble typesetting multi-line headers using `fancyhdr`
The header on the first page behaves differently than the header on subsequent pages. The first page header has no depth, but produces a greater vertical displacement on subsequent pages.

Here is a sample tex file to illustrate the difficulty

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\chead{line 1\\line 2\\line 3\\line 4\\line 5\\line 6\\line 7\\line 8}

\cfoot{footer}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
page 1 \newpage
page 2 \newpage
page 3 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You get a warning when you compile your MWE:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 94.54448pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

Adding `\setlength{\headheight}{96pt}` fixes the problem.

Comment: For an automatic solution, see [Heiko Oberdiek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek)'s [answer to a related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117810/6903).

Answer (score 1):

And the log-file is telling you

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 94.54448pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```