# How to determine head height automatically

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I'm creating three documents with three different headers, containing images or large banners. Is there a way to determine the head height automatically or even better a way to change the head height automatically with reference to the content?

I know LaTeX is telling me the head height is too small and I should change it to xx pt, but I would like to not have to do it manually.

A little excerpt of the beginning of one of my documents:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[paper = a4paper, tmargin = 2cm, bmargin = 2cm, lmargin = 2.5cm, rmargin = 2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{~\\[0.5cm]\includegraphics[height=2cm]{./dhbw_logo}}
    \fancyhead[R]{~\\[0.5cm]\includegraphics[width=2cm]{./cz_logo}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg Added a little excerpt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not think, it makes much sense to use an overlarge height of the titlepage's header for the whole document. Nonetheless the question is interesting in general.

Package `fancyhdr` already updates `\headheight` or `\footskip`, if the header or footer is too small. The following example stores the latest values of these dimension registers at the end of the document in an auxiliary file `\jobname.heights`. If the file exists, it is read in the preamble, before package `geometry` is loaded that might use the updated values for its calculations. Therefore the `.aux` file cannot be used for this purpose, because it is read a little too late (in `\begin{document}`).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \if@filesw % respect \nofiles
    \begingroup
      % same write register as environment `filecontents` uses
      \chardef\reserved@c=15 %
      \immediate\openout\reserved@c=\jobname.heights\relax
      \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
        \string\setlength{\string\headheight}{\the\headheight}%
      }%
      \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
        \string\setlength{\string\footskip}{\the\footskip}%
      }%
      \immediate\closeout\reserved@c
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.heights}{}{}

\usepackage[
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  a6paper,
  landscape,
  showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\Huge Header}
\cfoot{\Huge \begin{tabular}{c}Footer\\\thepage\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

### First run

Package `fancyhdr` warns:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 30.0pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (30.0pt): 
 Make it at least 50.99991pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

And the contents of the page is displaced:

> [image: First run]

### Second run

The previously written `\jobname.heights` is used:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{30.0pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{50.99991pt}
```

There are no warnings and the page is:

> [image: Second run]

## Workaround for package `calc`

Package `fancyhdr` has bugs, e.g. `\global\setlength` that does not work, if package `calc` is loaded. The following code patches the macro `\@fancyvbox`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\reserved@a#1#2{\setbox0\vbox{#2}\ifdim\ht0>#1\@fancywarning
  {\string#1 is too small (\the#1): ^^J Make it at least \the\ht0.^^J
    We now make it that large for the rest of the document.^^J
    This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however\@gobble}%
  \dimen0=#1\global\setlength{#1}{\ht0}\ht0=\dimen0\fi
  \box0}
\ifx\reserved@a\@fancyvbox
  \typeout{Patching \noexpand\@fancyvbox from package fancyhdr.}
  \def\@fancyvbox#1#2{%
    \setbox0\vbox{#2}%
    \ifdim\ht0>#1\relax
      \@fancywarning{%
        \string#1 is too small (\the#1): ^^J%
        Make it at least \the\ht0.^^J%
        We now make it that large for the rest of the document.^^J%
        This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however\@gobble%
      }%
      \dimen0=#1\relax
      \global#1=\ht0\relax
      \ht0=\dimen0 %
    \fi
    \box0 %
  }
\fi
\makeatother
```

The code should be inserted in the preamble *after* package `fancyhdr` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Oh `fancyhdr` updates it already if it's too large? Nice to know. This looks really nifty and I'll try it at home right after work. The only problem left and which I probably forgot to mention is that my headers contain data in all three sections of `fancyhead`. Is that a problem or does your solution always choose the right `\headheight`?

Comment: @Chris.V: It does not matter, how many sections of `\headheight` are used.

Comment: Yeah no that was my mistake. :) Hadn't thought the whole thing to the end. ^^ Thanks for your answer, it exactly does what I searched for.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work with the `calc` package, see my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353243/120953. David Carlisle noted there in a comment to his answer that "it isn't really safe to use `\chardef\reserved@c=15 %` it could be overwritten without warning by other writing in the document. It would be better to allocate a `\newwrite` for this use in the preamble and use that instead of 15, or just use `\@auxout` and write to the aux file which would simplify things and avoid having to re-input."

Comment: @jakun The use of `\reserved@c` is perfect safe here: (1) The meaning of `\reserved@c` is locally defined in a group and the previous meaning of `\reserved@c` gets restored after the group. (2) Also, the code in the group does not expand macros and therefore unaffected by a previously defined `\reserved@c`.

Comment: @jakun Write registers are a quite rare resource. Reusing an existing write register seems the better approach. In my answer, I had decided for the write register that environment `filecontents` uses. `\@auxout` is an alternative; the timing is more delicate, the `.aux` file must be written and the handle closed. This should be the case in the hook `\AtVeryEndDocument`. Or the entry is made in the `.aux` file in hook `\AfterLastShipout`. That also avoids an additional file.

Comment: I have only one page with a header using `\thispagestyle{fancy}`. Is it possible to use the same technique constrained to just this one page?

Comment: @JanHajer Have you tried it? What is the problem?

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek Indeed I did the mistake of polluting my example with a `\usepackage{mathtools}` which loads the `calc` package. As mentioned before the `calc` package interferes with this solution. Unfortunately the solution propsed in [tex.stackexchange.com/q/353243/120953](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353243/calc-package-prevents-headheight-to-change) doesn't compile for me.

Comment: @JanHajer See updated answer. It contains a patch for package `calc`.

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek, your patch seems not to work on my machine. I have added your new code directly in front of `\begin{document}` of your old code. The `calc` package still prevents your solution from working.

Comment: @JanHajer Make a new question with a full, but minimal example, add `\listfiles` to get the versions of the used packages. Maybe, add a link to the new question in a comment here.

Comment: @heiko-oberdiek, here is my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453329/automatically-determine-the-height-of-header-and-footer-in-the-presence-of-the). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JanHajer The internal macro prefix has changed from `\@fancy` to `\f@nch@`. Therefore, `\@fancyvbox` needs to be changed to `\f@nch@vbox` and `\@fancywarning` to `\f@nch@warning` in the patch for more recent version.

Answer (score 1):

> Package fancyhdr already updates \headheight or \footskip

Not entirely true: for accentuated letters, fancyhdr ignore the accents and sets the heights to that of the selected fontsize.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[RO, LE] {}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{nothing, just setting a weird title: l\`ik\'e s\^o}
    \newpage
\end{document}
```

In this example, fancyhdr puts `\headheight` to the size of 12pt's \Large for the title of the chapter in the head. However, a title with accents is bigger than without, and LaTeX adjusts the head height at the first title with such accents, leaving the first chapters with a different head height.

This should be fancyhdr default setting, depending on language. Instead, one can correct fancyhdr's oversight, if there are chapters with accentuated letters, using `calc`'s `heightof`. For french language, worst case scenario is circumflex accent, thus:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{\heightof{{\Large \^{E}}}}
```

fixes the headheight.