# fancyhdr's and accentuated letters

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing my thesis, in french. I also use fancyhdr. In the head of the page I have the chapter title. I had no problems for the first chapters, but the third include accentuation. I then had error messages telling me to increase headheight.
The package `fancyhdr` is supposed to figure out that size, but it overlooks accentuated letters.
To fix it, I tried to set a *relative* headheight by different means but so far I failed.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
% start fancyhdr tunning
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[RO, LE] {}
  % head too small. Local fix, setting bigger fixed value:
  %\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}    %commented out to get the headheight too small warning
% end fancyhdr tunning
\begin{document}
  \chapter{nothing, just setting a weird title: l\`ik\'e s\^o}
    \newpage
    what do you mean, this thesis null?
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions? I'm thinking a box that doesn't print, or a command which suppress printing, something like widthof from calc...?

Comment: I see no problem in setting the head height to a fixed value.

Comment: I might want to change the heading, and put it in LARGE. or change the font size. Regardless of code adaptivity, it wastes space when I could do with the exact needed size...

Comment: Then use `ex` or `em` units instead of `pt`. `\usepackage[headheight=1.5em]{geometry}`

Comment: `\setlength{\headheight}{100pt}\setlength{\topmargin}{-80pt}`. But if you expect to modify the heading, why shouldn't you expect to modify the head height?

Comment: @egreg: I don't mind modifying the heading on a whim, I do mind having to check the log to see which length I need to set, then modify it when it could be done automatically.

Comment: @harish-kumar: while the em/ex units could do the trick, as said in the question I'm being picky there: I don't like guessing the needed amount of ex, and wasting space when the select size is bigger than needed. Yeah I know...
I thought there was a more or less simple command to get a box in the preamble that I didn't know, starting to have doubts...

Comment: @luneart TeX can know the needed height only when it has typeset the heading.

Comment: @egreg: based on your comment I found this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117804/how-to-determine-head-height-automatically) that is more or less fine by me. Thank you!