# calc-package prevents \headheight to change

Tags: fancyhdr, calc

I am trying to automize setting the correct `\headheight` following [Heiko Oberdiek's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117810/120953). It is based on the fact that the `fancyhdr` package usually increases the `\headheight` as required and saves this value at the very end to a file. The problem is that when using the `calc` package that value does not seem to change (although the log file still claims "We now make it that large for the rest of the document.").

I know that I could avoid the `calc` package by using `\dimexpr` and friends but I need the `mathtools` package which requires the `calc` package.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the correct value for `\headheight` even if the `calc` package is used?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc} % this suppresses fancyhdr's feature of increasing \headheight as required


% ===== save header and footer height =====
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117810/120953
\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
    \if@filesw % respect \nofiles
        \begingroup
            % same write register as environment `filecontents` uses
            \chardef\reserved@c=15 %
            \immediate\openout\reserved@c=\jobname.heights\relax
            \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
                \string\setlength{\string\headheight}{\the\headheight}%
            }%
            \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
                \string\setlength{\string\footskip}{\the\footskip}%
            }%
            \immediate\closeout\reserved@c
        \endgroup
        \showthe\headheight
    \fi
}
\makeatother

%\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.heights}{}{} % I have commented this out for testing
\usepackage[
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    showframe,
]{geometry}


% ===== header & footer =====
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{a rather long header\\ which needs to be broken into several lines}
%\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\the\headheight-4.3501pt\relax]{icon}}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{page \thepage \ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{some footer}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


% ===== test document =====
\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: `fancyhdr` doesn't _usually_ increase headheight, it just warns, and increases it if the settings are inconsistent with the specified heading. Rather than use this file to save this error-correction it woul dbe more natural just to set up the correct settings using the geometry package in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fancyhdr` uses `\global\setlength` in one place which isn't supported LaTeX syntax and it doesn't work at all if `calc` is loaded. It is easy to avoid it in this case just delete `\setlength` and use a primitive assignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{calc} % this suppresses fancyhdr's feature of increasing \headheight as required


% ===== save header and footer height =====
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117810/120953
\usepackage{atveryend}
\makeatletter
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
    \if@filesw % respect \nofiles
        \begingroup
            % same write register as environment `filecontents` uses
            \chardef\reserved@c=15 %
            \immediate\openout\reserved@c=\jobname.heights\relax
            \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
                \string\setlength{\string\headheight}{\the\headheight}%
            }%
            \immediate\write\reserved@c{%
                \string\setlength{\string\footskip}{\the\footskip}%
            }%
            \immediate\closeout\reserved@c
        \endgroup
        \showthe\headheight
    \fi
}
\makeatother

%\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.heights}{}{} % I have commented this out for testing
\usepackage[
    includehead,
    includefoot,
    showframe,
]{geometry}


% ===== header & footer =====
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\def\@fancyvbox#1#2{\setbox0\vbox{#2}\ifdim\ht0>#1\@fancywarning
  {\string#1 is too small (\the#1): ^^J Make it at least \the\ht0.^^J
    We now make it that large for the rest of the document.^^J
    This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however\@gobble}%
  \dimen0=#1\relax
  \global#1\ht0\ht0=\dimen0\fi
  \box0}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{a rather long header\\ which needs to be broken into several lines}
%\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[height=\dimexpr\the\headheight-4.3501pt\relax]{icon}}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{page \thepage \ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{some footer}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


% ===== test document =====
\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I left your code as it is not relevant to the question but it isn't really safe to use `\chardef\reserved@c=15 %`  it could be overwritten without warning by other writing in the document.  It would be better to allocate a `\newwrite` for this use in the preamble and use that instead of 15, or just use `\@auxout` and write to the aux file which would simplify things and avoid having to re-input.

Comment: thank you, I will change that in my code. I had copied that from the answer I have provided a link to.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The use of `\reserved@c` is perfect safe here. See the grouping that restores the meaning of `\reserved@c`. Also, the code in the group does not contain macro expansion that avoids the problem, that a macro expands to and uses `\reserved@c`.

Comment: @Heiko it wasn't reserved@c I was worried about but \write15, filecontents is restricted to the beginning of the document so can assume its free but if someone has allocated \newwrites up to 15 then this may or may not trip up depending on the use

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it seems to me that the aux file would not be the desired way here because as Joseph Wright states in this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120978 the aux file is read _after_ the preamble but as far as I understand changing `\headheight` should happen _before_ loading the `geometry` package.

Comment: @jakun that could be fixed (geometry could be delayed) but actually I see no point at all in doing this if you are loading geometry. the `fancyhdr` setting is just a last-fallback fix if it finds the page settings are inconsistent, so it moans at the user to fix them. I can see it might possibly be useful to save that fix for next time (although why?  it's just as easy and a lot more robust to simply set headheight to the value specified) but if you are using geometry just use that package to set consistent settings and then fancyhdr will not complain.

Comment: @jakun Good point. A solution for using the auxiliary write handle could then look the following way: In `\AfterLastShipout` code can be added at the end of the `.aux` file that writes the file for the headheight and gets executed, when the `.aux` file is read again at the end of the LaTeX job.